# Rendering two overlapping 2D objects with 2 shaders

Tags: c++, opengl

I want to render two triangles in blue and a "windmill" in red. To do this I have created 2 shaders, which are the same except for the color. The two triangles are a lot bigger than the "windmill". The problem I'm facing is that if I switch between shaders, ONLY the last object will be rendered. If I switch to using only 1 shader, both objects will be drawn, but I can barely see the "windmill" because of the same color. So my question is how to draw both objects with two shaders? (I know I can just pass a color to the fragment shader, but I don't want to do that).

Render loop:

```
GLint index, index2;
index = glGetUniformLocation(shaders[LINE], "projectionMatrix");
index2 = glGetUniformLocation(shaders[TRIANGLE], "projectionMatrix");
glUniformMatrix3fv(index, 1, true, value_ptr(projectionMatrix));
glUniformMatrix3fv(index2, 1, true, value_ptr(projectionMatrix));
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

glUseProgram(shaders[TRIANGLE]);
glBindVertexArray(vaos[TRIANGLE]);
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, tbufindex/sizeof(glm::vec3));

glUseProgram(shaders[LINE]); // If I comment out this line both objects will be drawn
glBindVertexArray(vaos[LINE]);
glDrawArrays(GL_LINE_STRIP, 0, sizeof(vertices_position)/sizeof(glm::vec3));
```

Line/Triangle.vert:

```
#version 450
layout (location = 0) in vec3 vPosition;
uniform mat3 projectionMatrix;

void main()
{
    vec3 tmp = projectionMatrix*vPosition;
    gl_Position = vec4(tmp, 1.0f);
}
```

Line/triangle.frag:

```
#version 450
in vec4 gl_FragCoord;
out vec4 fColor;

void main()
{
    fColor = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0);
}
```

Also note that I don't have GL_DEPTH_TEST enabled, I'm using 2D coordinates.

Edit positions:

```
triangles[2] = { { vec3(-0.90f, -0.90f, 1.0f), vec3(0.85f, -0.90f, 1.0f), vec3(-0.90f, 0.85f, 1.0f) },
{ vec3(0.90f, -0.85f, 1.0f),  vec3(0.90f, 0.90f, 1.0f),  vec3(-0.85f, 0.90f, 1.0f) } };

lines[39] = {
    0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
    0.5f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
    0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f,
    0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
    0.0f, 0.5f, 1.0f,
    -0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f,
    0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
    -0.5f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
    -0.5f, -0.5f, 1.0f,
    0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
    0.0f, -0.5f, 1.0f,
    0.5f, -0.5f, 1.0f,
    0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f
};
```

Comment: I'd appreciate it if the down voters left a comment describing what is wrong with this question, so that I can explain the question better.

Comment: What are the positions of those primitives?

Comment: Added the positions, the 3rd coordinate is 1.0 so that I can use matrix multiplication to transform the triangles/lines.

Comment: Edit in a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`glUniform..()` must be called after binding the program ([source](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLSL_:_common_mistakes#glUniform_doesn.27t_work)). So the following should work:

```
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

glUseProgram(shaders[TRIANGLE]);
glUniformMatrix3fv(index2, 1, true, value_ptr(projectionMatrix));
glBindVertexArray(vaos[TRIANGLE]);
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, tbufindex/sizeof(glm::vec3));

glUseProgram(shaders[LINE]); // If I comment out this line both objects will be drawn
glUniformMatrix3fv(index, 1, true, value_ptr(projectionMatrix));
glBindVertexArray(vaos[LINE]);
glDrawArrays(GL_LINE_STRIP, 0, sizeof(vertices_position)/sizeof(glm::vec3));
```